# Is it true there is only one other place in the bible we can find the number 666?

Tags: solomon, 666

Is it true there is only one other place in the bible we can find the number 666 ? I read it was related to the amount of the gold king Solomon could gather in one month (or year, I don't remember).

Comment: as per the [answer given by user17470](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/35188/10486) - a simple search on biblegateway reveals 4 verses: https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=666&qs_version=NIV

Comment: one other... than what?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is trivial and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) Please draft future questions to fit into one of those types.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is trivial. A simple and quick search on any concordance software reveals the answer. Google is also very effective.

Comment: I didn't know about biblegateway. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ezra 2:13
 the sons of Ad·o·ni′kam, 666

2 Chronicles 9:13 & 1 Kings 10:14
 And the weight of the gold that came to Sol′o·mon in one year amounted to 666 talents of gold,

Revelation 13:18
 This is where it calls for wisdom: Let the one who has insight calculate the number of the wild beast, for it is a man’s number, and its number is 666.